# How do I flip a bit using bitwise operator for an int in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a flags column in sql which is an int.

I need to set a bit in the flag with a SQL statement. The corresponding C++ statement looks something like `flags &= ~(unsigned long) (0x10000000)`.

I tried to do

```
update [Databases]
 set flags = flags & ~0x10000000
```

but i get a

```
Operand data type varbinary is invalid for '~' operator.
```

Then I tried to see what the convert function would yeild

```
select flagInt = CONVERT(int , 0x10000000)
```

gives me 268435456.

```
select flagIntInvert = ~CONVERT(int , 0x10000000)
```

gives me  -268435457

which is the same as the signed int

```
flag    268435456   int
        ~flag   -268435457  int
```

However I need the unsigned versions

```
(uint32)flag    268435456   unsigned long
~(uint32)flag   4026531839  unsigned long
```

**Is there a way to set the flag to be the inversion of 0x10000000**?

Thanks.

Comment: how about update [Databases] set flags = flags ^ 268435456?

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but perhaps: http://www.julian-kuiters.id.au/article.php/sqlserver2005-unsigned-integer

Comment: the bitwise NOT is indeed ~ in SQL however but your issue seems more with signed/unsigned int than bitwise. I think however it might be faster for you to simply write a small application which fetches, updates and saves the values via code, because as shown in the above comment - if you want to work with unsigned values you'll have to make your own type (or go BIGINT and rework the logic)

Answer (score 4):

Setting the inversion of the flag can be used but applying the bitwise NOT operator ~.
The int in SQL Server is an signed int.

From what I can see you want to active a bit in an integer and that can be done using the following statements.

Assume you are having an integer with value 1, i.e. the first bit is active.

```
DECLARE @Value int = 1;
```

And you want to active the third bit you use the or-operator (|) as below:

```
SET @Value = @Value | 4;
```

This will render the value 5 of the int variable.

```
SELECT @Value;
```

If you then want to check if the third bit is set in use the following, which will filter of all other active bits:

```
SELECT @Value & 4
```

And if you want to use it in comparing use the following statement:

```
IF @Value & 4 = 4 ...
```

Hope this helps.